# Java multi threading - Write only if no other threads are reading

Tags: multithreading, java-8, locking

I have a map which holds some data similar to an in memory cache.

```
Map<String,Object> map;
```

There are multiple theads which are reading the data from the map. Each thread may read the data more than one time.

```
public void processData(){
  ...
  map.get("something");
  ...
  map.get("someOther");
  ...
}
```

The map needs to be updated with latest values from database. I use a webservice for that.

```
public void refreshService(){
  //this code should wait until no one is reading the data
  map.clear();
  map.put("latestFromDb",readData());

}
```

The requirement is that my web service should wait until all the reading threads are finished. So that the readers should get either the old data fully or the new data fully.
**Edit**: <strike>The reading threads should not wait for anything.</strike> The reading thread can wait for the web service(Since this is infrequent). but the reading threads should not wait for other reading threads.

Which java 8 lock/mechanism/design pattern I can use to implement this.

Comment: _ The reading threads should not wait for anything_ Then what is the expected result when a thread wants to read data while `refreshService` is running? Did you already take a look at `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: And then, the real answer here is: when you are tasked to write real world production code, then **you** should understand the option space to a certain degree. Meaning: you should step back, and study the advanced concurrency approaches that Java has to offer these days. Then you try something, and maybe ask here for further clarification.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with “step back and study” but not with “try something” when it comes to concurrency. Too many people do “try something” and think they got a solution because it happened to do the desired thing on that try.

Comment: @Holger point taken.

Answer (score 2):

Since the reading operation queries the map multiple times, the only way to get a consistent result (without locking), is to never modify the map at all.

In other words, instead of calling `clear()`, instantiate a new map, populate it, and change the `map` reference to point to the new map, as an atomic update. Don’t forget that the read operation must not read `map` multiple times then, but copy the current reference into a local variable right at the beginning.

```java
volatile Map<String, Object> map;
```

```java
public void processData(){
    Map<String, Object> map = this.map;
    ...
    map.get("something");
    ...
    map.get("someOther");
    ...
}
```

```java
public void refreshService() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("latestFromDb", readData());
    ...
    this.map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}
```

Wrapping the map with `unmodifiableMap` is not strictly necessary, but will help spotting errors, as any modification beyond this point would lead to nondeterministic behavior, including the possibility to never spot the problem during testing. Therefore, replacing the nondeterministic behavior with deterministically throwing an exception on subsequent modification attempts, is preferable.